# how use python model model to extract feature?

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, classification, layer

I train a python model  that make object classification . Then, I want to use this model to as a feature extractor but i donot know the all name of layers. the code is

```
base_model = load_model('models/deepfake-detection-model.h5')
base_model.summary()

for layer in base_model.layers:
    print(layer.name)


#extract = Model(model.inputs, layer_n) # Dense(128,...)

data= cv2.imread('dataset/real/eudeqjhdfd_4.png')

#features = extract.predict(data)
for l in base_model.layers:
    print (l.output_shape)

layer_n=inception_resnet_v2
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer(layer_n).output)
```

I used the model summary function to get the layers name of model but the output is

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
inception_resnet_v2 (Model)  (None, None, None, 1536)  54336736  
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Gl (None, 1536)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 2)                 3074      
=================================================================
Total params: 54,339,810
Trainable params: 54,279,266
Non-trainable params: 60,544
_________________________________________________________________

inception_resnet_v2
global_average_pooling2d
denseb

(None, None, None, 1536)
(None, 1536)
(None, 2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\Hamdy\Project of Gradition\code\python\hh.py", line 26, in <module>
   layer_n=inception_resnet_v2
NameError: name 'inception_resnet_v2' is not defined
```

Can anyone help me by telling how to know the name of model layers and uses it as a feature extraction technique?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: I attached the code and detailed output error